# how to solve pg pool error connection to front end

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, pgpool

I am using `pgpool` for managing **`postgres`** databases cluster that deployed with k8s,

and I faced this error:

```
ERROR: unable to read data from front end
DETAIL: EOF encountered with front end
```

anyone know about this?